# How to set the path for repository local pre-commit hooks

Tags: pre-commit.com

[Pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) allows [repository local hooks](https://pre-commit.com/#repository-local-hooks) which are useful for project-specific lints.

For hooks with the language `script` you can specify its path just using `entry`, e.g:

```yaml
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: check-x
        name: Check X
        entry: ./bin/check-x.sh
        language: script
```

However when you use the language `python`, the `entry` is just the name of the entry point of the Python package to use. How can I tell it where the Python package is located within my repo?

Answer (score -1):

despite your assertion, `entry` is *not* the python package -- but the executable to be used.  it is common that this matches the python package provided, but is not a requirement or a guarantee for python packaging (pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks has many examples where they do not match)

pre-commit never installs the repository under test so you'll not have access to any executables that may be provided by packages there.

for `repo: local`, `language: python` can refer to either executables provided by things in `additional_dependencies` or it can be paths to scripts within your repository (the same as `language: script`)

---

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Comment: I didn't say `entry` is the Python package, but anyway this doesn't really answer the question: how do I tell pre-commit where my package is? I.e. the directory containing `pyproject.toml`.

Comment: I *think* that the answer is "you can't" which kind of sucks because it means you can't have repo-specific limits written in Python that use third party dependencies.

Comment: *lints, not limits

Comment: you can't install your package, but you can have scripts with additional_dependencies